# DPM simpleXMLElement returns just the object but echo returns its value

Tags: debugging

When I DPM the simpleXMLElementObject it returns

> (Object) SimpleXMLElement

print_r returns the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => c1e1c959-c99d-42f0-8a44-2998b )
```

Although when I echo I can see the value for my object. Thus what is the best way to get its value in a string format?

This way then I can process that information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that dpm was not printing some of the SimpleXMLElement values. They were only visible from the var_dump after die. Maybe there is a better way to check these. What I noticed was the value was being generated but dpm was not showing it and var_dump did.